# Reflexive relation without mentioning the set it is on

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read from my book something like this:

> Let $R \subseteq A^2$ be a binary relation. If $R$ is *reflexive*, then...

Saying that some relation is *reflexive* without mentioning the set it is on confuses me. I think what author meant was that if $(a, b) \in R$, then $(a, a) \in R$ and $(b, b) \in R$.

Must $R$ be reflexive for entire $A$ (I mean $\forall a \in A [(a,a) \in R]$)?

Comment: If $R \subseteq A^2$ then you have a binary relation on the set $A$...

Comment: ... and thus for all $a \in A$, you have $(a,a) \in R$.

Comment: @Théophile: How did you get that "for all $a \in A$"? Suppose $R = \{(a,a)\}$ for one $a \in A$. So $R$ contains only one pair and $R \subseteq A^2$ and $R$ is *reflexive*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ (the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$). Here it is given that $R \subseteq A^2 = A \times A$, so the set is $A$.

$R$ is reflexive, implies that for some subset $A'$ of $A$, we have $(a, a) \in R, \forall a \in A'$. Then $R$ is actually not a reflexive on $A$ (unless $A' = A$). I think in all probability, the author means the relation is reflexive on $A$, so $\forall a \in A, (a, a) \in R$.

**Edit:** In the book 'Introduction to Set Theory', *Jech*, that you found this in, the author defines a $R \subseteq A^2$ as a *binary relation $R$ in $A$* (see Definition 2.13, page 22). Later he defines a *reflexive relation $R$ in $A$* as one for which $\forall a \in A, aRa$ (see Definition 4.1, page 29).

Comment: Should $(a,a)$ be in $R$ for all $a \in A$? Maybe the author meant that $R$ is defined on some subset $X \subseteq A$ and it is *reflexive* only for $X$?

Comment: @Graduate I was wondering the same, but I think the author meant $R$ to be reflexive on $A$ itself. Otherwise, $R$ is not a reflexive relation on $A$, and $R \subseteq A^2$ is misleading (although technically true). Which book is this? It might be clear from the context.

Comment: *Jech*, "Introduction to Set Theory," page 63, Exercise 5.15.

Answer (score 3):

Reflexivity of a relation makes no sense without reference to the underlying set.

Say you have a set of ordered pairs
$$R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) \}$$
Then $R$ is reflexive as a relation on the set $\{1,2,3\}$, but is not reflexive as a relation on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, for instance. It makes no sense to say "$R$ is reflexive" unless we already know what the underlying set is... in fact, to be really pedantic, it doesn't even make sense to say $R$ is a relation until an underlying set has been specified.

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ satisfying the property that, if $a \in A$ is related to anything then $(a,a) \in R$, is said to be *quasi-reflexive*. That is, $R$ is a quasi-reflexive relation on $A$ if it is a reflexive relation on some subset of $A$.

Contrast this pickle with symmetry and transitivity; these are intrinsic to the relation and do not depend on the underlying set.